# Adjunction: Why does modding out by a polynomial "add" the zero of the polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose we have a ring R and we form a polynomial ring in R, R[x].  In class my professor has explained that forming the quotient ring of R with some polynomial f(x), is like adding the zero of that polynomial to the ring.  What is really going on in the background with this intuition?

Comment: Asked and answered [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/633928/242)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but take a simple example: say $R={\Bbb Z}$ and $f(x)=x^2-2$, and let $\alpha=\sqrt2$ be one of its roots.  In $R[\sqrt2]$ we can simplify by using the fact that $\alpha^2=2$, say
$$(1+2\alpha)(3+4\alpha)=3+10\alpha+8\alpha^2=19+10\alpha\ .$$
In $R[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ we simplify by removing multiples of $f(x)$, for example,
$$\eqalign{(1+2x)(3+4x)
  &=3+10x+8x^2\cr
  &=19+10x+8(x^2-2)\cr
  &\equiv19+10x\pmod{f(x)}\ .\cr}$$
Hope this sheds some light on why these two processes are essentially the same.